# php using files in the parent folder

Tags: php

Is there any way to use a php file in the parent folder. I have a tree like this

```
\
- index.php
- requirements.php
\Learning Center
 - index.php
```

When in the root folder, I can call `./requirements.php`, but i cannot do this from inside the Learning Center folder.

In an attempt to fix this, I used the full url path to the file, but now I get this error:

Warning: require_once() [function.require-once]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration

I cannot change the server configuration, is there any way for me to refer to the requirements.php file from inside the Learning Center folder? I do not want to resort to putting a copy of all the resources I need into each folder.

Note: Sorry if this sounds like a stupid question, but I have only been programming in php for 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `../requirements.php` instead.  ../ is the next directory up from the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use the absolute path not the url

```
Eg: require '/var/www/html/learning/xyz.php' ;

not require 'www.example.com/learning/xyz.php' ;
```

Comment: thats the hard part, I'm using a free hosting service and I have no idea what the absolute path is.

Comment: use something like dir(_ _file_ _)."../xyz.php" or simply ../xyz.php

Comment: Once again, free hosting service is restricting what I can do

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) to obtain the root directory.

Comment: I get this error when I tried that: 

open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/www//login.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (VIRTUAL_DOCUMENT_ROOT)